# Using Parse as BaaS to store multiple images in an efficient manner

Tags: database-design, parse-platform

I am using parse to make an ecommerce application for IOS and Android. 
I have a Product Table (or class) that has all the product related information like Price, Description etc. I am struggling to find the most efficient way of storing images
Every product has about 10-15 images and I want a good UI at client end in terms of image download. Following are the methods I can think

1. Create additional 15 columns in Product table with  Type to store images.
2. Create an Array in Product table and store multiple images (Don't know if its possible)
3. Save all Images in a new Table  with an Object reference of Product Table.
4. Save images on some external server and make array of image URLs in Product table

What can be the best solution in terms of speed and Minimum API calls. 
Please advice. Does anyone also know about an image hosting server that can work in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me go through each of your methods and highlight the pros and cons of each.

---

- **Create additional 15 columns in Product table with Type to store images.**

  1. It is ofcourse possible and apparently good if you have 3-4 images. But in this case you have 15 and I don't think it is a good idea to add that much columns into a table row to do this. That is definitely not the way Parse.com supposed to be used. :)
  2. On the other side of the argument, you get all the file references to your images related to a particular product in 1 network request.
  3. If you are using the conventional `byte[]` method supported by the Android SDK, you might run into problems because the data can eat up your memory if not handled properly.
  4. Column naming (say if you are going to use `image1, image 2, image3 ...`) can cause further effort when you need to fetch the data back.
  5. If the number of images is not 15 exactly, it causes further coding efforts for cross checking if a particular column contains a valid image.

---

- **Create an Array in Product table and store multiple images (Don't know if its possible)**

  1. You can definitely do that using arrays. To do that, use the normal file upload method and grab the file url using `parseFile.getUrl()` on Android and `PFFile.url` on iOS. Then add it to the images array column you have. You can also use JSONArrays to do the same.
  2. This is definitely not a good idea either because you don't have the opportunity to scale or manipulate the file further using cloud code or scheduled jobs.

---

- **Save all Images in a new Table with an Object reference of Product Table.**

  1. This is exactly the way it should be done.
  2. The only issue with this implementation is that you don't get the reference to the images when you query for the products with one network request.
  3. But you can always make use of the relational data implementation for this. [Read this](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers)

---

- **Save images on some external server and make array of image URLs in Product table**

  1. If you have the facility you can do that as well. Parse's image processing capabilities are not that good. You can make use of other services if it is economical.

Comment: Can you please suggest any service with good Image processing capability and fast response rate. I have limited expertise here.

Answer (score 0):

Use any 3rd party CDN for bitmap backend.

The interface to above is type String(uri-on-CDN)

In parse, wrap the 15 uris above in an array and store that as a column data-type.

Store a parse-pointer to the above row with the array in the physical parse table that you want to query against.

That way, you can just use the parse expression "include=$pointerName" in any query needing to provide access to the arrayRef and to the 15 uri values.

Comment: Can you please suggest a good CDN that has a fast response rate.

Comment: im in san fran and for that i looked at rackspace , AWS , parse.com.

Comment: I am already using Parse to host my Tables. How can I upload images to Parse and get their UUID. I mean is there a manual way of doing it

Comment: Look at file section of docs 4 how upload bitmap to parse. Uuid is in json response of the upload post. Best is rest API using curl 2 test uploads.